# How to write custom validation pattern for Phone number

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to write custom validation for phone Number(India) my problem is it should validate for both mobile number and landline number. I'm thankful if anyone gives me a solution for this
my validation code

```
contact:['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern("/^[0-9]{10,10}$/")]],
```

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngIf="(submitted||f.contact.touched) && f.contact.invalid" class="error-msg">
    <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.required">contact  is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.pattern">Please enter 10 digit Number</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! you can but feel free to post your tried code

Comment: here is my validation code    
 contact:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("/^[0-9]{10,10}$/")]] 

 and my html 
  <div *ngIf="(submitted||f.contact.touched) && f.contact.invalid" class="error-msg">
                            <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.required">contact  is required</div>
                            <div *ngIf="f.contact.errors.pattern">Please enter 10 digit Number</div>
                          </div>

Comment: Can you please tell us the requirements? For ex: It should accept min `X` and max `X` number and other

Comment: it should accept 10 digit mobile number and also 12 digit landline number

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
contact = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]{10,12}$")]);
```

Regex: `^[0-9]{10,12}$`

Where,

```
[0,9]   - Accept 0 to 9 numbers
{10,12} - Range
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rszpxz)

Answer (score 0):

This is a phone validation for angular app

If you want a validation with country code

```
export class CustomValidators {
  static phoneNumber(countryPhoneCode = '*'): ValidatorFn {
    return Validators.pattern('([+]'+ countryPhoneCode + ')?([0-9]{9,12})$');
  }

}
```

Now use it in your form group

```
this.formbuilder.group({
      phone: ['', [CustomValidators.phoneNumber('237')]]
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are referring to validate that user has entered valid code number (area code, mobile number prefix) I think you should write a custom validator. Maybe the best way to do is do a server side validation so, you can add or change logic of validation without re-deploying the frontend.